# SQL create new string column by substracting two other string columns

Tags: sql, string, substring

I am trying to create a new column by substracting two other columns NameVer and Ver. Basically the output should have a value of Name - Ver, e.g. Adam Philips-10021 - 10021 = Adam Philips (I also need the last dash before the Ver deleted).

I have a following table:

| NameVer | Ver |
| --- | --- |
| Dr. Cristine Pharrel HF-10021 | 10021 |
| Mary-2Jane Jean-CF2331 | CF2331 |
| Michael 1772 d'Oro-1027763 | 1027763 |

What I am trying to achieve is this table:

| NameVer | Ver | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dr. Cristine Pharrel HF-10021 | 10021 | Dr. Cristine Pharrel HF |
| Mary-2Jane Jean-CF2331 | CF2331 | Mary-2Jane Jean |
| Michael 1772 d'Oro-1027763 | 1027763 | Michael 1772 d'Oro |

Strings as you can are see consisted of various characters, sometimes a dash occurs not only before the Ver part but also somewhere in the middle. Moreover, I have discovered that some of string in both columns have empty spaces beyond visible characters.

I have tried using the following code:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NameVer, 1, LEN(Ver)+1)
from myTable
```

unfortunately, instead of for instance `Dr. Cristine Pharrel HF`  I got `Dr. Cr`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using the following method:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NameVer,1, LEN(NameVer) - LEN(Ver) -1)
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a plain `REPLACE` here:

```sql
SELECT
    NameVer,
    Ver,
    REPLACE(NameVer, '-' + Ver, '') AS Name
FROM myTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo